# How to "read" a user account with Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

I am trying to create a backup powershell script for user documents. I have created a script where I am putting on a form box the username I want to backup and then the script proceeds. The last thing is that I want to have a rule that if I put a wrong name, the script will not proceed.

Does anyone knows how I can "read" the present useraccounts on a laptop, in order to create rule to cross-check the input with the useraccounts?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read all of the folders in `C:\Users` and attempt to find a corresponding account in AD:

```
Get-Childitem C:\users -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        $profilePath = $_.FullName

        Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $_.Name} |
            ForEach-Object {
                New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $_.Name -PassThru |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProfilePath -Value $profilePath -PassThru |
                    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SID -Value $_.SID -PassThru
        }

    } | Format-Table Name,SID, profilePath -AutoSize
```

Obviously you can modify to get different AD properties, if needed.  Also, remove the `Format-Table` command in order to pipe the output objects for further manipulation.

Note:

- This requires the [AD PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) to be installed on the system you run the script on.
- It only outputs an object if it finds a user account, so you won't see anything for folders it finds that have no account.

Comment: Really Helpful, thank you for your time! I will try to somehow export the results and make a comparison with the variable I am using

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" | Select Name
```

will give you names of local accounts. Other available fields for select are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Although this is relevant in what I am looking for, the problem is that the results I want to have are exactly as the users are appearing on the path C:\Users. The command you sent me returns different results, considering that the account I am mostly interested in is a domain account, the results cannot be used. Is there another solution?